# public key in HEX format to EC_KEY using c++

Tags: c++, openssl

I have a public key in hex format in c++ code. I have to convert this public key to EC_KEY structure which is used by openssl to verify the signature. The problem is that I am not able to convert hex string to pem format from which openssl can generate the public key.

Tried: 
1. I convert the hex string to bytes. (I guess this converts to ascii format)
2. this byte string to converted to base64 (ascii format to base64 encoding)
3. use PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY to get the public key  (read as pem)
4. EC_KEY_check_key fails.

```
static const char b64_table[65] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

static std::string base64_encode(const ::std::string& bindata)
{
    using ::std::string;
    using ::std::numeric_limits;

    if (bindata.size() > ((numeric_limits<string::size_type>::max)() / 4u) * 3u)
    {
        throw ::std::length_error("Converting too large a string to base64.");
    }

    const ::std::size_t binlen = bindata.size();
    // Use = signs so the end is properly padded.
    string retval((((binlen + 2) / 3) * 4), '=');
    ::std::size_t outpos = 0;
    int bits_collected = 0;
    unsigned int accumulator = 0;
    const string::const_iterator binend = bindata.end();

    for (string::const_iterator i = bindata.begin(); i != binend; ++i) {
        accumulator = (accumulator << 8) | (*i & 0xffu);
        bits_collected += 8;
        while (bits_collected >= 6) {
            bits_collected -= 6;
            retval[outpos++] = b64_table[(accumulator >> bits_collected) & 0x3fu];
        }
    }
    if (bits_collected > 0) { // Any trailing bits that are missing.
        assert(bits_collected < 6);
        accumulator <<= 6 - bits_collected;
        retval[outpos++] = b64_table[accumulator & 0x3fu];
    }
    assert(outpos >= (retval.size() - 2));
    assert(outpos <= retval.size());
    return retval;
}


std::string HexToBytes(const std::string& hex)
{
    std::string bytes;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
        std::string byteString = hex.substr(i, 2);
        char byte = (char)strtol(byteString.c_str(), NULL, 16);
        bytes.push_back(byte);
    }

    return bytes;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Set up the public key.... 
    std::string sPubKeyString = "E3A7E51FE102286D071026111088F680761FDCD7031E3D56244BBE07451601E78AD08AD40EADCF380900985A1FAB94DE6D02DB91920F1144E9EBC4E248444969";

    std::string sKeyInAscii = HexToBytes(sPubKeyString);

    std::string sPub64(base64_encode(sKeyInAscii));
    std::string sKeyInPem = std::string("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n") + sPub64 + std::string("\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");

    const char* pzKey = sKeyInPem.c_str();
    std::unique_ptr< BIO, std::function<void(BIO*)>> bo(BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()), [](BIO* b) { BIO_free(b); });
    BIO_write(bo.get(), pzKey, strlen(pzKey));
    std::unique_ptr< EC_KEY, std::function<void(EC_KEY*)>> zPublicKey(EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1), [](EC_KEY* b) { EC_KEY_free(b); });
    EC_KEY* pPubKey = zPublicKey.get();
    PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY(bo.get(), &pPubKey, NULL, NULL);

    if (EC_KEY_check_key(pPubKey) == 1) {
        printf("EC Key valid.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("EC Key Invalid!\n");
    }
}
```

This code prints EC Key Invalid. I dont know what wrong I am doing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `std::vector<char>` instead of `std::string` or any string functions when you are dealing with binary data, since `'\0'` is a perfectly valid value in such data but has a special meaning in strings.  Beyond this, instead of scratching your head over the final result and then asking on Stack Overflow, try examining your data at all steps of the process to determine whether it matches what you expect.  For example, try writing it to file and then looking at it in a hex editor.  Or work it through by hand and check your program produces the same intermediate results.

Comment: Hex to pem conversion is good.  I verified this using this website  https://holtstrom.com/michael/tools/hextopem.php.  I entered the hex string which I used and output which the code generates with the output of this site. Both the outputs are same. I think the way I am using key is wrong